# May "garden" be used as a verb?

Tags: word-usage, word-class

When my hobby is gardening, what I'm doing in the free time? Can I say:

> "I will garden tomorrow."

or perhaps:

> "I'm going to garden some roses."

Or can I ask someone how to garden tomatoes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may say "I will garden tomorrow", but you are more likely to say "I'm gardening tomorrow".

Generally, *garden* is used as an intransitive verb meaning "to cultivate or tend one's garden"; one may also *garden* a plot of ground, meaning make a garden in it, but one does not *garden* a plant or crop. You might *grow* roses, or *tend* or *cultivate* them.

Comment: Indeed one may use _garden_ as a verb like that, but I'd guess most gardeners would be more prone to say something along the lines of, "I will work in the garden tomorrow." As you point out, though, one wording may be less common, but that doesn't make it wrong, or ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/garden) suggests that *garden* can be a verb.

More than that, it can be either *transitive* or *intransitive* (used without or without an object):

- Transitive:

  - To cultivate (a plot of ground) as a garden;
  - To furnish with a garden;
- Intransitive:

  - To plant or tend a garden;
  - To work as a gardener;

I don't think that *"I will garden tomorrow"* is very grammatical, but *"I decided that it's better to garden tomorrow than today"* seems fine to me.

Comment: I would not recommend the OP to use this as a verb, not in its transitive sense anyway. It's just not used that often and could cause people to stare at him in bewilderment. It's better to stick with phrases like *tending to the garden* or *growing some vegetables in the garden*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use garden as a verb, such as "I will garden tomorrow", or "I like spending time alone gardening", but I don't think you can use an direct object with garden ("I'm going to garden some roses").  A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+garden+tomatoes) for "How to garden tomatoes" only turns up results on "How to grow tomatoes".

Comment: You meant direct object surely?